# The virtual path [path] maps to another application

Tags: c#, asp.net

> The virtual path maps to another application  Which Is Not Allowed.

I get this error when trying to access `ConfigurationManager.Connectionstrings[KEY]` .

I did the solution of setting the virtual path to `"/"` but it does not work. I have changed the application name (it is different to the foldername of the project).

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the application name and as you said it is different from the foldername of the project then look for .sln file(Solution file) in the project folder. open this file in editor(Notepad) and correct the path of the project here.

I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: There is no path in csproject file

Comment: Look for .sln(Solution) file in project folder instead of .csproj you will see your old name of application there change this to new name and it will work.